# Error while trying to assign a custom role "Secret Reader" to an object ID for an Azure Key Vault

Tags: azure-keyvault, azure-cli, azure-rbac

Can anyone tell me why i am getting this error while trying to run this command and assign a custom role "Secret Reader" to a guest account Object Id :

az role assignment create --role "Secret Reader" --assignee-object-id "12526c57-c91b-405b-9068-2b582b23e83a" --scope "/subscriptions/Not-putting this-here/resourceGroups/pallabdev/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/testhalvault"

The error i get is :

```
request failed: Error occurred in request., InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'C:/Program Files/Git/subscriptions/Not-Putting-This-Here/resourceGroups/pallabdev/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/testhalvault/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions?$filter=roleName%20eq%20%27Secret%20Reader%27&api-version=2018-01-01-preview'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the error message, I suppose you ran the command in Git Bash of Windows, I can also reproduce this on my side, it was caused by the [Auto-translation of Resource IDs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/dev/doc/use_cli_with_git_bash.md#auto-translation-of-resource-ids) in Git Bash, similar issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/16317).

To solve this issue, just set environment variable `MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1` or set it temporarily when you running the command.

```
$ MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1 az role assignment create --role "Secret Reader" --assignee-object-id "12526c57-c91b-405b-9068-2b582b23e83a" --scope "/subscriptions/Not-putting this-here/resourceGroups/pallabdev/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/testhalvault"
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I simply ran the command using the Windows `powershell` instead of `Gitbash` and it worked like a charm.